# How to apply transition all on adding and removing a class with helper class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I am trying to add transition on adding and removing (toggling) to classes `.fa-heart-o` and `.fa-heart` and using a helper class called `.fa-heart-slow` like this. But as you can see the `.fa-heart-slow` is not adding any transition there.

How can I fix this?

```js
$(".table").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".fa").removeClass('fa-heart-o').addClass('fa-heart fa-heart-slow');

}, function() {
  $(this).find(".fa").removeClass('fa-heart-slow fa-heart').addClass('fa-heart-o');

});
```

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.fa-heart-slow {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that works the way you intend, since switching `.fa` classes effectively switches the `content` property of the element and the `content` property is not one that's listed as supporting transition animations in the W3 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-css

That said, a simple way to create the same effect would be to have two icons overlapping each other - one of each `.fa` class - then use pure CSS to animate the desired behavior on hover. This can be achieved with the following.

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><i class="fa fa-heart-o icon-default"></i><i class="fa fa-heart icon-hover"></i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table .fa {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
.icon-hover {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -16px;
  position: relative;
}
.table:hover .icon-default {
  opacity: 0;
}
.table:hover .icon-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

First I set the transition for `1s ease` per your example; we only set it for `opacity` since that's the only property changing. Then I set the the second `.fa` icon (`.icon-hover`) to `opacity:0` and place it behind the primary one (`.icon-default`).

Finally, a `:hover` rule is applied to switch the opacity of the two icons when hovering over the `.table` element; combined with the `transition` property previously defined, the two appear to cross fade in/out.

CodePen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VELLgj